# Pass Button id to MVC Controller from View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a button in my .cshtml page.
I want to pass the id of the button to the controller action. 
Here is what I have currently:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div id="report">@Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "Parameterize", "Report", new { Id = @item.Id }, null )</div><br /><br />                           
    <input id="@item.Id" type="button" onclick="Test()" class="button1" value="Update" />

}
```

In Firebug I can see that the id is properly fetched:

[image]

Now in the js code, here is what I am trying, but for some reason the id is still null in the controller action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Test() {       
        var itemId = $('#report').attr('id');
            var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateReport/", "Report")';
            var data = { Id:itemId };
              $.post(url, data, function (result) {
                  var id = '#postedFor' + postId;
                  $(id).html(result);

            });                   
    }
</script>
```

In the controller action I have this, and the id is null at this time:

```
 public ActionResult UpdateReport(string id)
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Every advice is more then welcome.
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're generating *many* `<div>` elements with exactly the same "id" value.  The "id" of an element must be unique on the whole page, or else weird things will happen.

Thus, `$('#report')` is not going to work properly. Maybe you could do:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div id="report_@item.Id">@Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "Parameterize", "Report", new { Id = @item.Id }, null )</div><br /><br />                           
    <input id="@item.Id" type="button" onclick="Test()" class="button1" value="Update" />

}
```

Alternatively, you could pass the input element directly to the handler:

```
  <input id="@item.Id" type="button" onclick="Test(this)" class="button1" value="Update" />
```

Then:

```
function Test(item) {       
    var itemId = item.id,
        var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateReport/", "Report")';
        var data = { Id:itemId };
          $.post(url, data, function (result) {
              var id = '#postedFor' + postId;
              $(id).html(result);

        });                   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var itemId = $('#report').attr('id');
```

is fetching the id of your div with the id report.

You want to pass the button to the function test() and use it to get its id:

```
<input id="@item.Id" type="button" onclick="Test(this)" ...
```

And then in your js Test() function:

```
var itemId = $(this).attr('Id');
```

Also note, that the attribute names are case sensitive. You wrote "id", but your attribute is called "Id".

Comment: thanks for your reply but var itemId = $(this).attr('Id');
gives me null value as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector looks off:

```
var itemId = $('#report').attr('id');
```

That is going to get the `id` value of an element with an `id` of `report`.  I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: But it's just a function definition; if it's not called until an event happens it's OK for it to be outside a "ready" handler.